# handling multiple posts on single route with bottle

Tags: python, post, bottle

I have two forms that needs to "post" on the same route.

1. is "search" which is part of the base template across all routes on the app and
2. which is to "submit" and is specific to a route and is part of the child template.

How can/do I differentiate between the two "post"?

In bottle I am trying to pick out the "POST" request by using the "name" of the form - what should the code look like?

**Bottle:**

```
@route('/pending', method=['GET', 'POST'])
def pending():
session = db_session
if (request.POST.get('name') == 'search_request'):
    return "search"
if (request.POST.get('name') == 'submit_asset'):
    return "submit"
    session = db_session
    format_id = request.forms.get('submit_asset')
    print format_id
    result_format_metadata = session.query(FormatMetadata).filter(FormatMetadata.id==format_id).first()
    result_format_metadata.id = format_id
    result_format_metadata.stateid = 4
    session.commit()
    redirect("/pending")
```

Here is the form from the base template which is search function on a nav bar and is on all routes:

```
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search" method="post" >
    <div class="form-group">
      <input name="search_request" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" >
    </div>
  </form>
```

and here is the submit form which is specific to the /pending route:

```
<form action="/pending" method="post"><button name="submit_asset" value="{{row.format_id}}"/>Submit</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found it:

```
@route('/pending', method=['GET', 'POST'])
def musicvideopending():
session = db_session
if request.forms.get('search_request'):
    print "search"
elif request.forms.get('submit_asset'):
    print "submit"
    format_id = request.forms.get('submit_asset')
    print format_id
    result_format_metadata = session.query(FormatMetadata).filter(FormatMetadata.id==format_id).first()
    result_format_metadata.id = format_id
    result_format_metadata.stateid = 4
    session.commit()
    redirect("/pending")
else:
    print "nothing"
    date = "2015-11-19 23:14:06"
    result_video = session.query(FormatMetadata).filter(FormatMetadata.id).all()
    result_videoID = FormatMetadata.id
    result_pending = session.query(Metadata).filter(Metadata.format_id==result_videoID).filter(FormatMetadata.stateid==1).all()
    result_md_done = session.query(Metadata).filter(Metadata.format_id==result_videoID).filter(FormatMetadata.stateid==3).all()
    result_date_24h = session.query(Metadata).filter(Metadata.format_id==result_videoID).filter(FormatMetadata.created_date).all()
    output = template("pending", rows_pending=result_pending, rows_md_done=result_md_done, rows_per_24=result_date_24h, start_date=date, end_date=date)
    return output
```

Basicall I just needed to move the if statement to the top of the function and use `request.forms.get` to identify which form does the post